# Load Printer Name

Tags: visual-studio

I want to write code in C# for loading printer name in window. But I don't have any ideas to write it.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx). For an example see the linked page.